# Matching Reynolds numbers in microfluidics

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, simulations

I am working with lattice Boltzmann simulations of multiphase flow. The Reynolds number from experiments is $\mathcal{O}(10^{-3})$. For stability reasons, the closest match I can get in simulation is $\mathcal{O}(10^{-1})$. So my question is how important is the match between the two values for flow similarity.

Comment: Does $\mathcal O(-3)$ mean the value is actually about -3 or about $10^{-3}$?

Comment: Good point - a common abuse of notation. See edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A flow is only similar when all the characteristic dimensionless numbers are equal. Only in that case are the terms in the Navier-Stokes equations of similar magnitude at different scales.

The rule of thumb is that dimensionless numbers can vary by an order of magnitude, e.g. if $Re=O(1)$ then it can vary between $Re=0.3-3$ and still be considered $O(1)$. Given that you are off by two orders of magnitude, I would argue that your simulation result are not obtained under the same conditions as the experiment.

As for the stability problems in LBM, generally these are the result of limitations on the numerical viscosity (related through the relaxation time). However it should be possible to keep the viscosity in the stable region and simply reduce the flow speed to match the Reynolds number. Your simulation will take longer to run but atleast the flow conditions are kept the same.

Comment: All valid comments, thank you. The first point you make is my concern, too. My reasoning, however, was that since Re is mainly used to predict flow regime transition, which does not occur in my scenario, a mismatch, provided that Re<<1 will not pose a problem. Ma is also a characteristic dimensionless number but to match it I will need u~10^-6... This is however a known problem and people doing LBM do not necessarily match it. What are your thoughts on that.

Comment: @PeterHristov i would need more context on the intent of your simulation. You mention multiphase flow, shapes of droplets/bubbles depend on Reynolds numbers among other dimensions numbers.  So it can well be that bubbles/droplets are mismatched also.

Comment: Could you point me to some literature, if you are aware of any? Thanks!

Comment: @PeterHristov I don't know of any literature regarding microchannels but check out the bubble shape regime map in [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0045793013003605) article to see my point regarding bubble shape dependence on the Reynolds number. Although I have to say if it is low enough any bubble tends to be spherical. Also I don't know if the regime map is extendable to microflows. Good luck

Comment: I will check! Thank you for all the  the helpful advice!